# fatfree framework, bug pr misuse?

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

i have this db function in f3 framework

```
public function sumOfAmount($startdate, $enddate) {
    $this->amount = 'price*quantity';
    $this->sumamount = 'SUM(price*quantity)';
    $this->load(array('createon > ? AND createon < ?', $startdate, $enddate));

    //return $this->query;
    return $this->cast();
}
```

it seem that sumamount is not correct , from the f3 log i have this query executed

```
SELECT `idproduct`,`idtransaction`,`idline`,`name`,`code`,`price`,`quantity`,`createon`,(price * quantity) AS `amount`,(SUM(price * quantity)) AS `sumamount` FROM `qrysales`
```

but if i run that query in phpmyadmin result is ok

Any idea??

Comment: `SELECT column, column, ... SUM(..) ...` is pretty wierd annyway mixing non-aggregated columns with a aggregated column without using a GROUP BY.. When the server is using `sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` it's even invalid SQL

Comment: Can you clarify what's exactly the issue? "it seem that sumamount is not correct" doesn't give much information.

Comment: indeed, you have not defined any group by rule.. add it to $options

Answer (score 1):

it seems that i forgot group by clause

```
public function sumOfAmount($startdate, $enddate) {
    $this->amount = 'price*quantity';
    $this->sumamount = 'SUM(price*quantity)';
    $this->load(array('createon > ? AND createon < ?', $startdate, $enddate,'group' => 'idline'));

    //return $this->query;
    return $this->cast();
}
```

Comment: 3 1/2 years to solve the problem, you are super dedicated!